# Capacity of assets, res and libs folders

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror

What is the capacity of the `assets`, `res` and `libs` folders in Android?

There are almost 11MB of `*.so` files in my `libs`, and almost 8MB of resource files in `assets` and `res`. Now, when the I need more resources — 1MB or more — there is an error:

> `UnsatisfiedLinkError`: `findLibrary` returned `null`.

Actually, several `*.so` files can't be found in `/data/data/myapp/lib`, and the missing `*.so` files appeared to be based on the size of my resources. The more resources I put in my app, the more `*.so`s were missing.

By the way, this is just in Android 2.x. I tested it on my HTC with Android 2.3.7; my Galaxy S2 with Android 4.2.2 worked perfectly.

===============================================================

cause by default,application will be installed on the internal storage in my 2.x device,sometimes it run out of.

changed:specify the android:installLocation="preferExternal" or android:installLocation="auto" in manifest so the data could install on the external storage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there are any size limits for assets, res and libs. Just make sure that they have proper file-names. i.e File names must be lower cased etc.

Comment: thanks for your help,but it's funny that ,such as i want a mp4 just like 1.6MB,it crash just by the UnsatisfiedLinkError,while i put a little small 600KB mp4 ,it make sence.so ,here it's the resouces in my raw folder.Also ,in assets,i have a gpk,if the gpk is a little bigger ,it crash.by the way,*.so is ok,and also work perfect in another project.

Comment: i mean ,what i changed is nothing but the size of the resouces.